# Is JavaSamplerClient the right way to test this setup?

Tags: jmeter

I have a java server that communicates with java clients over the network. What I want to do is to verify that they are maintaining state and gather performance statistics for the server. I've used JMeter to test web services in the past and thought to use it to test this server.

The clients are pretty simple and only send and receive a few message types. They login to the server and create a session id. Then they can do a number of transactions using that id, get text data, send text data, ping to verify the connection is alive and finally logout.

Initially I thought I'd wrap the client code in a JavaSamplerClient, but having read the javadocs again I'm not sure that is a good idea. JavaSamplerClient looks like it expects to do one thing and return the same kind of data. But I want to not only return the performance numbers, but I want to verify that the state of the client and check that the data is not being corrupted.

Is using JavaSamplerClient in JMeter the right thing to use here or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaSamplerClient can do everything you'll implement.

For instance, if you create your class as follows:

```
public class MySampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
@Override
public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    return;
}

@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
    return null;
}
```

If you don't intent to use GUI for sampler you can omit `setupTest` and `getDefaultParameters` methods and leave only `runTest` one.

Your test code should be placed inside `runTest` method. It returns an instance of [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) which is fully controllable.

for instance:

`result.setResponseCode()` - set response code based on any condition
`result.setResponseMessage()` - the same for response message

The bit you're looking for is probably

`result.setResponseData()` - here you can make your sampler to return anything you want.

Reference material: [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I guess I have in mind the idea of creating, say, 100 clients and having them all stress the server, then shutting them all down at some point and return their results. But it looks like JavaSamplerClient requires that each simulated client be bound by one call to the runTest method, right? Like a one-shot? Is there a way to instantiate simulated clients within JMeter and have JavaSamplerClients that tell them to when to login, stress for N seconds, then logout, all in tandem or in sequence?

Comment: JavaSamplerClient can be used as any other sampler so they obey to JMeter Logic controllers, respect ramp-up settings, loops, etc. If you need to get them to work at the same time - you'll need to consider using Synchronizing Timer. If you don't want all steps (login, stress, logout) in the same Sampler you'll need to consider intercommunication via JMeter Variables, like login sampler returns some ticket or cookie, than stress sampler uses this ticket to authenticate itself, then ticket is used for logout.

Comment: I wrote a JavaSamplerClient to test the basic idea with a time-to-live connection and it was relatively easy to do, so this seems a good approach. The trickiest part was customizing the build process. I'm not sure if passing state around different samplers will work well or not, I need to do a bit more experimentation in that area. 

For now I am going to focus on the beset way to structure my data for the SampleResult such that I can create some detailed reports after the tests complete. Do you have any insight on that part of the process? Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to access JMeter Variables and Properties from JavaSamplerClient code so passing state isn't a problem at all.